# Badge spacing in top bar is misleading

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I just glanced at my badges and was very confused why I only had two silvers...

[image]

It took me a few seconds to realize that the spacing was off. Compare to meta:

[image]

I don't know if the difference is truly meta-vs-main or if its caused by the gold badge.

This is happening on Chrome / Windows 7 x64. Confirmed in IE 8 as well.

Comment: It's not caused by the gold badge - I see similar behavior with just bronze badges.

Comment: I see this with Firefox 3.6.28 on WinXP, too.

Comment: and Firefox 12.0, too.

Comment: Same on Firefox 12.0 on Mac OS 10.6.8

Answer (score 2):

A fix for this will be pushed in the next build, > rev 2012.5.9.2511.

Comment: still seeing odd spacing in FF12 W7.

Comment: Fixed for me now. Thanks!